# Use Angular's ng-show in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

I've already knew I can use **Laravel variable** in html class and define it in angular file. Here's the code that I said about it :

**master.blade.php:**

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div class =" {{ statusClass }} ">
   .
   .
   .
  </div>
</div>
```

**main.js:**

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('AppCtrl',[...,function(...){
                 .
                 .
                 .

                    timeout(function () {
                    $scope.statusClass = "active";
                    $scope.visibility = false;

                }, 0);

}])
```

Now I just want to use show/hide specific div.

```
  <div class =" @{{ statusClass }} " ng-show =" @{{ visibility }}">
```

But as we know we cannot use this type of variable in ng-show. Any suggestion?

Comment: `ng-show="visibility"` will show when true and hide when false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up angular with blade here.

`@{{visibility}}` will render to `{{visibility}}` where angular expects an expression, not an angular render tag.

The correct way would be:

```
<div class =" @{{ statusClass }} " ng-show ="visibility">
```

As a side note, it is always better to you `ng-if` instead of `ng-show` or `ng-hide`, as explained [here](http://www.codelord.net/2015/07/28/angular-performance-ng-show-vs-ng-if/)

Also I would mention that it is bad practice to evaluate a class name directly from angular, better use `ng-class` for this.

Comment: first of all , I did not down vote your answer. second, Thanks for your comment.